# HighCharts - how to set dynamically margins?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

i would like to fit my highcharts chart into my bootstrap grid, so that it fits nicely with the other content.

The whole should look like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col-1 | Col-10 | Col-1 |
| X-Axis Labels | Chart plot-area | 2. Axis labels |
| Col-1 | Col-10 | Col-1 |

I think marginLeft and marginRight should be the right options, but they accepts only number-values, so i'm not able to tell them the bootstrap percent-values.

My config looks like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: "column",
marginLeft: 65 // <= Dynamically or percent?
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    }
},

series: [{ }]
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8oh5uwn/)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically calculate and set margins based on some percentage value, for example:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            render: function() {
                if (allowChartUpdate) {
                    var dynamicMargin = this.chartWidth * 8.333333 / 100;
                    allowChartUpdate = false;

                    this.update({
                        chart: {
                            marginLeft: dynamicMargin,
                            marginRight: dynamicMargin
                        }
                    }, true, true, false);

                    allowChartUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/913scgxa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thank you! I've never noticed the events-section before

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to separate elements of the chart into different columns, it'd be quite simple to achieve the same visual effect using CSS (assuming a fixed-width chart axis/`.col-1`): https://jsfiddle.net/7z93n1md/1/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
    type: "column",
    marginLeft: 65 // <= Dynamically or percent?
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }]

});
```

```css
.container-fluid .col-1,
.container-fluid .col-10{
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}
.highcharts-figure {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%,
}

/* Added the below */
.row .col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 65px;
  max-width: 65px;
}

.row .col-10 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 130px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 130px);
  padding: 0;
}

.row .col-12 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 65px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 65px);
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">Col-1</div>
  <div class="col-10">Col-10</div>
  <div class="col-1">Col-1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
   <figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A brilliant solution! Thank You. The problem is the fixed first column which needs to be flexible.

Comment: You're welcome :) It seems highcarts only allows setting [marginLeft](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft) to a pixel value, so either it needs to be fixed, or `.col-1` needs to be styled to match the automatic width of the chart's default dynamic margin if marginLeft is not set. Maybe there's another charting library that would allow this?